# How to view rendered code from Google Mobile Friendly Test API using curl?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm running mobile friendly test with curl and it's working fine, from this URL:

https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api/v1/getting-started

Code I run is this:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{url: "https://www.example.com" , "requestScreenshot": true}' 'https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/v1/urlTestingTools/mobileFriendlyTest:run?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

It all works fine, but then it prints out the image code in Json, and it's humongous!

Is that SVG? How can I view the image?

Code is like this:

```
"data": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAZwAAALcCAYAAADT8QbIAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFUeJzs3Xl4VNXBBvD3zp5k
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPDO9.png)

https://pasteboard.co/I6jRIqj.png

Comment: The data is a base64-encoded string. https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api/reference/rest/v1/urlTestingTools.mobileFriendlyTest/run#Image

Comment: Yes, I see that, but I've tried to decode it with online tools, but it's not working...maybe I'm doing something wrong? Bin is here:  https://pastebin.com/Zrwgm7xd

Comment: I cannot understand your current situation from your reply. Can you provide the detail information about ``it's not working``? If my comment was not useful for your situation, I have to apologize.

Comment: Is this still working [Link](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api/v1/getting-started)? Tried it but it doesn't work on my end.